# Personennamen: Genitiv-Spezialfall?

Tags: grammatical-case, genitive, person-names

In einem Buch ist mir der Genitiv untergekommen:

> ... und spielte zwei oder drei Lieder Walther von der Vogelweides.

Mir ist schon klar, dass der Satz mit einem andere Namen, etwa *Franz Schuberts*, gut funktionieren würde. Da nach *von der* für Vogelweide aber nur der Dativ in Frage kommt und außerdem  *Vogelweide* klar weiblich ist, stolpere ich über das angehängte *s*.

Gibt es eine andere Lösung als durch Umformulieren den Genitiv zu vermeiden?

In *Walther von der Vogelweide: Eine biographische Skizze* findet sich die Alternative, die den Genitiv nur auf Walther bezieht:

> Die Wiederherstellung des Grabdenkmals Walthers von der Vogelweide...

Für ein ähnliches Namensmuster, *Reinmar der Alte*, wird der Genitiv als *Reinmars des Alten* gebildet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Das *-s* des Eigennamen-Genitivs wird hinter dem Namen angehängt. Es entsteht aber eine Unsicherheit dadurch, dass es zwei verschiedene Auffassungen darüber gibt, ob nun der Zusatz *von der Vogelweide* als Teil des Eigennamens gilt oder nicht:

1. Entweder wird der Zusatz als integraler Teil des Eigennamens aufgefasst – der Eigenname lautet dann gewissermassen *Walther-von-der-Vogelweide* –
2. oder der Zusatz wird als ein optionales Anhängsel aufgefasst – der Eigenname lautet dann gewissermassen *Walther ([übrigens kommt er] von der Vogelweide).*

Im ersten Fall ergibt das Anhängen des Eigennamen-Genitiv-*s* die Form *Walther-von-der-Vogelweide-s,* im zweiten Fall hingegen *Walther-s (von der Vogelweide).*

Bemerkungen:

- Traditionell gilt die zweite Auffassung als korrekt, also die Form *Walthers von der Vogelweide.*
- Bei einer Voranstellung würde wohl nur noch die erste Auffassung akzeptiert, (also beispielsweise *Walther von der Vogelweides Gedichte),* während die zweite Auffassung heutzutage inakzeptable oder zumindest altertümlich erscheint (vgl. *Walthers von der Vogelweide Gedichte).*
- Die Umschreibung mit *von* ist holprig wegen des doppelten Auftretens *(von* Walther *von* der Vogelweide).
- Vgl. auch [*Walthers von der Vogelweide* oder *Walther von der Vogelweides* — Komplexe Eigennamen im Genitiv • Grammatik in Fragen und Antworten](http://hypermedia.ids-mannheim.de/call/public/fragen.ansicht?v_id=18).

Comment: Abweichend von deiner Auffassung nehme ich *die Lieder Walthers von der Vogelweide* auch heute als korrekt wahr und *die Lieder Walther von der Vogelweides* als so richtig als spräche man von *seinen vielgesungensten Liedern* - schlicht eine Folge des *Sprechen ohne Nachdenkens*.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: Wie kommst du denn darauf, dass ich die zweite Form nicht als korrekt wahrnähme? Selbstverständlich dünkt sie mich korrekt. Wie hältst du es übrigens mit der Voranstellung?

Comment: Das ist doch Unfug, in Punkt 2! "Von der Vogelweide" ist der Nachname, keine Herkunftsbezeichnung, auch wenn der Name auf eine Herkunftsbezeichnung zurückgeht. Man kann den Vornamen weglassen und der Name bleibt "von der Vogelweide". "Von der Vogelweide schrieb mehrere Lieder" würde man schreiben und müsste kein Der als Ersatz für den Vornamen davorsetzen. Nimm aktuell zirkulierende Namen wie "von der Leyen", "aus der Au" oder "zu Guttenberg" um Dich zu überzeugen.

Comment: @userunknown: Nein, man lässt eben nicht den vermeintlichen Vornamen weg, sondern man schreibt «Walther schrieb mehrere Lieder», denn bei «von der Vogelweide» handelt es sich eben gerade nicht um einen modernen Nachnamen, sondern um einen mittelalterlichen Namenszusatz aus einer Zeit, als sich Nachnamen noch gar nicht durchgesetzt hatten. Vgl. dazu etwa [Walther von der Vogelweide](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walter_von_der_Vogelweide) oder die zahlreichen Quellen dort.

Comment: @mach: Das Mittelalter ist aber vorbei. Der Adel abgeschafft. Wir reden und schreiben heute anders. Sprachhistoriker, die sich in der Sprache der damaligen Zeit unterhalten wollen, dürfen das selbstverständlich gerne tun. Die Frage ist aber allgemein gestellt und von der Vogelweide nur ein griffiges Beispiel. Siehe auch die Überschrift.

Comment: @userunknown: Hier geht es eben nicht um persönliche Meinungen, sondern um den Sprachgebrauch, wie er bei den sorgfältigsten Schreibenden üblich ist, also in gut redigierten Büchern, Feuilletons usw. Und da ist es nun einmal so, dass die Form «Walthers von der Vogelweide» üblich ist. Ob es einem nun gefällt oder nicht, ist eine ganz andere Frage und tut erst einmal nichts zur Sache.

Comment: Richtig, es geht um den Sprachgebrauch, und "Walther von der Vogelweide" war nur ein Beispiel, die eigentliche Frage, die geklärt werden soll, und heute ist "von der" ein Namensbestandteil. Das hat der Frager auch in der Überschrift herausgestellt: Personennamen, nicht Herkunftsbezeichnungen. Mit Meinung oder Gefallen habe ich gar nicht argumentiert - zwei Strohmänner. Übrigens gefällt mir generell, was richtig ist.

Comment: @userunknown: Nun, was ist sie denn, «die eigentliche Frage, die geklärt werden soll»? Selbstverständlich lautet das erste Wort im Titel «Personennamen». Danach geht es aber weiter mit «Genitiv-Spezialfall?» Und im Beitrag sind als Beispiele zwei Namen von Minnesängern aufgeführt. Mir scheint es also sehr offensichtlich um mittelalterliche Namen mit «von der» zu gehen, und insbesondere darum, ob sie einen «Spezialfall» darstellten – wobei ich sinnvollerweise die modernen Namen mit «von der» als impliziten Normalfall dazudenke. Die Antwort ist: ja, sie stellen einen Spezialfall dar.

Comment: *Spezialfall* bezieht sich auf Personennamen, im Ggs. zu Landschaftsbezeichnungen zum Beispiel, wie *von der Kuhweide*. Ich finde das offensichtlich, da Mittelalter oder veralteter Sprachgebrauch nicht thematisiert werden, aber der Wegfall des Genetiv-S als Option, wie bei den Juwelen der Christel von der Post.

Comment: @userunknown: Es ist mir rätselhaft, wie du auf veralteten Sprachgebrauch kommst. Der Genitiv-Spezialfall bei mittelalterlichen Personennamen (mit Herkunftsbezeichnung) ist eine unbestreitbare Tatsache *in der modernen Sprache.* Solche Texte werden heute in modernem Deutsch geschrieben von Leuten, die sich richtig gut auskennen. Beispiele findest du etwa in sorgfältig redigierten Büchern oder in den Feuilletons der besten Zeitungen usw. usw.

Comment: Mit veraltetem Sprachgebrauch meine ich, jemanden als "Werner von der Dorfaue" zu bezeichnen, der nicht "von der Dorfaue" heißt, sondern da herkommt. Das war damals Sprachgebrauch - unbestritten, und das wissen so manche mit großer Allgemeinbildung, auch unbestritten. Ich bestreite, dass das die Intention der Frage war.

Comment: Dann sind wir uns ja einig: In sorgfältig geschriebenen Texten von Leuten, die sich gut auskennen, kommt bei Personennamen aus dem Mittelalter ein Genitiv-Spezialfall vor, und zwar in der modernen Sprache. Die Intention der Frage kennen wir nicht. Wir kennen bloss die Frage – wo explizit ein «Spezialfall» erwähnt und ausschliesslich mittelalterliche Personennamen genannt werden – sowie die akzeptierte Antwort. Daraus mag man schliessen, was man will.

Answer (score 2):

Dieser Genitiv ist durchaus korrekt, und findet sich auch vielfach im Internet:

- [Wikipedia über Gerhard Atze](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerhard_Atze):

  > Gerhard Atze <sub>[...]</sub> war ein Dienstmann <sub>[...]</sub>, auf den zwei Lieder **Walther von der Vogelweides** um 1204 und 1205 Bezug nehmen.
- [Wien Geschichte Wiki über W.v.d.V.](https://www.wien.gv.at/wiki/index.php?title=Walther_von_der_Vogelweide):

  > Lehrzeit und Aufstieg **Walther von der Vogelweides** als Sänger ...
- [Titel einer Hausarbeit auf Grin](http://www.grin.com/de/e-book/203918/ueberzeugungsstrategien-in-walther-von-der-vogelweides-sangspruchdichtung):

  > Überzeugungsstrategien in **Walther von der Vogelweides** Sangspruchdichtung

Alle genannten Beispiele, lassen sich auch mit *von + Dativ* formulieren, ohne die Bedeutung zu ändern:

> - Gerhard Atze <sub>[...]</sub> war ein Dienstmann <sub>[...]</sub>, auf den zwei Lieder **von Walther von der Vogelweide** um 1204 und 1205 Bezug nehmen.
> - Lehrzeit und Aufstieg **von Walther von der Vogelweide** als Sänger ...
> - Überzeugungsstrategien in der Sangspruchdichtung **von Walther von der Vogelweide**

Und genau dasselbe ist auch in deinem Beispiel möglich:

> ... und spielte zwei oder drei Lieder **von Walther von der Vogelweide.**

Answer (score -3):

> Da nach von der für Vogelweide aber nur der Dativ in Frage kommt und
>   außerdem Vogelweide klar weiblich ist, stolpere ich über das
>   angehängte s.

Das ist falsch. "Von der Vogelweide" ist der Nachname, bzw. wie ein Nachname, in dem eine grammatische Form quasi geronnen ist. Egal, ob man von Müller, Meier, Schulz noch 20 Euro zu kriegen hat, oder von von der Vogelweide, man braucht ein eigenes *von*. Der Vorname ist ja nicht zwingend zu gebrauchen.

> Gibt es eine andere Lösung als durch Umformulieren den Genitiv zu
>   vermeiden?

Ja. Beziehungsweise nein. Man kann den Genitiv verwenden und das angehängte S umschiffen:

```
Er spielte drei Lieder des Walther von der Vogelweide.
```

Daran ändert auch nichts, dass es das heutige Namenssystem zu Zeiten des Walter von der Vogelweide noch nicht gab.